# keep divs inline with each other

Tags: html, css

I cannot push the `side div` and `container div` in my html code to the background or atleast inline with the other divs. As I have set a border on the divs in my css, it causes `<div id="side">` to show above every other div, the same is also happening to `<div id="container"`? This causes these divs to float over the rest of the divs:

[image]

You can see the issue here:

```
body {
    min-height:100%; 
}
div { 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #F6F4F4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    transform-style: inherit;

}
```

Comment: can you describe in normal language goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have expanded on the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Still not very clear. Is your issue the fact that the sidebars make the scrolled content visible under the header? If it is, it's an issue with your handling of the CSS overflow property.

Comment: Hi that is an issue i can fix later but if you look at the output you can clearly see the "side" div over the content/menu and advertisement divs. the shadow cast from the box border is really evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `z-index:-1` in #side and #container . For example http://jsfiddle.net/d3u1fqfa/3/

Answer (score 0):

try adding a z-index option to the container in css.
the z-index defines when two or more tags overlap which one of them should be on top the default is `z-index:0;` so if you try `z:-index:-1;` it might solve the problem you are having